# Basic Mutex's causing program to lock up in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I've got a simple C program that uses mutex's to collect a char from the standard input on one thread and print it out on another thread.  Both threads start correctly (the printf in the below saying that the thread started runs), but then neither of the while's get run since I introduced Mutex'.  Does anyone have an idea as to why?  (I collect two chars in my char array as I am collecting the return char as well.)

Thanks!

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct thread_info {    /* Used as argument to thread_start() */
        pthread_t thread_id;/* ID returned by pthread_create() */
        char passedChar[2];
        pthread_mutex_t passedCharMutex;
        pthread_cond_t conditionalSignal;
};

static void *thread_1_start(void *arg) {
        struct thread_info *myInfo = arg;
        printf("Started thread id: %d\n", myInfo->thread_id);
        while (1) {
                printf("thread1 while ran");
                pthread_mutex_lock(&myInfo->passedCharMutex);
                int rid = read(0,myInfo->passedChar,2);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&myInfo->passedCharMutex);
        }
        pthread_exit(0);
}

int main() {
        struct thread_info tinfo;
        printf("Main thread id: %d\n", tinfo.thread_id);

        int s = pthread_create(&tinfo.thread_id,
                NULL, // was address of attr, error as this was not initialised.
                &thread_1_start,
                &tinfo);
        pthread_join(tinfo.thread_id,NULL);

        while (1) {
                printf("thread2 while ran");
                pthread_mutex_lock(&tinfo.passedCharMutex);
                write(1,tinfo.passedChar,2);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&tinfo.passedCharMutex);
        }
}
```

Comment: UB. initialize the mutex

Comment: And after you fix that, you may want to think about what that mutex is really protecting, especially. There is no spoon. I.e. the thread is gone (you just joined it) and consequently your `main()` while-loop is locking a mutex for latched access to a buffer that no other thread is accessing to begin with, at least not anymore. Not that it will ever get that far, since your thread will run indefinitely, therefore `main()` hangs on the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthread_mutex_t and pthread_cond_t must be intitialized before you can use them.

```
struct thread_info tinfo;
pthread_mutex_init(&tinfo.passedCharMutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&tinfo.conditionalSignal, NULL);
```

In this case you could initialize them when initializing the `tinfo` variable too:

```
struct thread_info tinfo = {
     .passedCharMutex  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
     .conditionalSignal = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
};
```

You also have a

```
 pthread_join(tinfo.thread_id,NULL);
```

after you create your first thread, that will cause you wait until your thread ends, which it never does since thread_1_start() runs an infinite loop - you'll never reach the while loop in main().

While not part of your question, there's additional problems:

There's no synchronization of the logic of your two threads. As it currently stands, they both run without any regard to eachother, so your main() might print out `passedChar` many times before your thread_1_start() reads anything.

Likewise, thread_1_start() might read a lot of data before your main() thread have a chance to print it.

What you probably want is:

- Thread A: read 2 chars
- Thread A: signal Thread B that there is 2 chars to process
- Thread A: wait until Thread B has processed the 2 chars.
- Thread B: wait for thread A to signal that there's 2 chars to process
- Thread B: process the 2 chars
- Thread B: signal Thread A that we're done process

Comment: Thanks - I had just worked out I needed to use the second option above for initialisation (worked fine), and re-read what join did (left over from my last program that I didn't clean up properly).  Thank you for pointing out about the logic sync in my threads - I hadn't got that far yet - but yes, you are right.  Will fix and edit correct code into the post afterwards.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When thread 1 comes to this line,

```
int rid = read(0,myInfo->passedChar,2);
```

it holds the lock and then blocks for input. Tread 2 waits for the thread 1 to exit. And if no input ever comes neither thread will make progress.

Comment: in this instance, that is the intended behaviour.  Thread 2 should be blocked until it can get the lock on the char array, which only happens after thread1 has got user input.